# How to dismiss alert without pressing enter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to dismiss JavaScript `alert()` programatically OR by pressing any key and not necessarily pressing the ENTER key?

Comment: ALL JavaScript is blocked until the alert continues

Comment: No. Alert is synchronous and can only be operated on by the user.

Comment: You shouldn't use alert on a real application in most cases. Try an alternative like sweet alert

Comment: use setTimeout()

Answer (score 2):

You may try [boot box plugin](http://bootboxjs.com/)

```js
var alert = bootbox.alert('Count to 5...');
alert.show();
setTimeout(function() { alert.modal('hide'); }, 5000);
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I took the liberty to change it to a runnable snippet with CDN links :-)

Comment: your welcome dear :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `ESC` key instead of `Enter`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21550125)

Comment: I must disagree, it does provide an answer to the question. It provides *direct* answer to the question. Let me quote OP: "Is there any way to dismiss [...] alert() programatically *OR* by pressing any key and not necessarily pressing the ENTER key?". And the answer is - yes, you can dismiss `alert()` by pressing any other key than enter - the key is ESC. And this is what I suggested